# How to defer a function execution in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to defer a function execution. My current approach is something like this:

```bash
do_afterwards () {
    sleep 2
    echo "do something later"
}

do_afterwards &
start_my_webserver & start_monitoring_webserver
```

`start_my_webserver & start_monitoring_webserver` will run in the foreground of my terminal and "block it". I want to run `do_afterwards` after my Webservers started. Currently I am doing that simply with a dummy wait. How can I do this smarter?

Comment: Without further details, I don't think we can help. If as you say the service is a web server, wait until it actually responds to requests on port 80?

Comment: It does not really matter what it is. If it succeeds it will block the terminal. If it fails the script will end. I want to run the deferred function if `start_my_webserver & start_monitoring_webserver` succeeds.

Comment: That's easy to do by making them conditional. `start_monitoring_webserver && echo "do something later"`

Comment: @User12547645: It does matter, though - because it's otherwise impossible for a script to tell the difference between "started successfully and blocking the terminal" and "taking a while but going to fail". There needs to be a way (such as checking for the web server's socket being up) to determine what counts as "success".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is how to start both do_afterwards and start_monitoring_webserver simultaneously after start_my_webserver finished, then the following could work:

```
do_afterwards () {
    echo "do something later"
}

start_my_webserver () {
  echo "starting"
  sleep 2
  echo "started"
}

start_monitoring_webserver () {
  echo "monitoring"
  sleep 2
  echo "monitoring"
  sleep 2
  echo "monitoring"
}

post_start() {
  do_afterwards &
  start_monitoring_webserver
}

start_my_webserver && post_start
```

Result:

```
starting
started
monitoring
do something later
monitoring
monitoring
```